# Error propagation calculation yielding negative variance

Tags: standard-deviation, error-propagation

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation of the sum X = A + B.

A and B are mean values, and I do not have access to the source data.

A is 0.46 with an SD of 0.014 (SDa) and B is 0.375 with an SD of 0.018 (SDb).

Using SPSS and a different dataset measuring A and B in a different population I have concluded that A and B are correlated with a correlation coefficient of -0.4 and covariance of -0.00037 (COV). I find it propable that the relationship between A and B should be similar between populations and I am therefore then using this covariance as an estimation of the covariance in the dataset from where A and B are derived.

To the best of my knowledge, the equation to calculate the SD of X = A + B (SDx) should then be:

SDx = SQRT(SDa^2 + SDb^2 + 2*COV)

This, however, gives a negative number to take the sqare root from, i.e. a negative variance for X, resulting in SDx being a complex number.

A negative variance should not be possible, so I'm clearly making a mistake somewhere, but I can't figure it out. I couldn't find this specific question answered here before, so I thought I'd reach out and ask for some help.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Best regards, 
Mattias

Comment: How did you come up with -0.00037 for the covariance?

Comment: I took the same variables from a different population, one where I have all the original data, and used the "Bivariate correlations"-tool in SPSS, ticking in the box for "cross product deviations and covariances", this yielded the output pearsons r = -0.4 and covariance = -0.00037.

Comment: Unfortunately that value of covariance is mathematically impossible, as you have discovered.  Because you are using two different sets of data for your estimates, there is no reason the estimates need to be consistent.

Comment: Yes, I suppose I can not use that estimation of covariance. Thank you for your input, much appreciated!